# Change sheet cells color onEdit

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell

I figured out how to compare dates in Google Sheets but when I try to enter more dates for some reason all the cells that were green and red become all red. Also how can I make two cells red if only one cell has a date?

Example:  In cell D18 the Due date is 4-18-2014 and in cell E18 the cell is blank. I want to make both cells red so I would know that I should find out why is that cell red.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Project Sheet 1');
var values1Rule1 = s.getRange('E2:E1000').getValues();
var values2Rule1 = s.getRange('D2:D1000').getValues();
var range3Rule1 = s.getRange('D2:E2');
var color1 = 'Red';
var color2 = 'Green';

for (var row in values1Rule1) {
for (var col in values1Rule1[row]) {
if (values1Rule1[row][col] > values2Rule1[row][col]) s.getRange(s.getRange('D2').offset(row, col, 1, 2).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color1);
else if (values1Rule1[row][col] < values2Rule1[row][col]) s.getRange(s.getRange('D2').offset(row, col, 1, 2).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor(color2);
  else s.getRange(s.getRange('D2').offset(row, col, 1, 2).getA1Notation()).setBackgroundColor('white'); }}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add this condition as an OR clause in your red condition, e.g.

```js
if (values1Rule1[row][col] > values2Rule1[row][col] || values1Rule1[row][col] === '')
```

But there's lots of "minor" problems with your code. First of all, you're doing way too many API calls unnecessarily. This is a big performance issue. For example, when you `offset`, you already have the new range, there's no need to `getA1Notation` then get the range again, you could do:

```js
s.getRange('D2').offset(row, col, 1, 2).setBackgroundColor(color1);
```

But that's still two calls, getting `D2`, then offseting. You could get the desired range at once:

```js
s.getRange(row+1, 4, 1, 2).setBackgroundColor(color1);
```

I'd go even further and build a matrix of colors and set it all at once after the loop:

```js
s.getRange('D2:E1000').setBackgroundColors(colors);
```

But even better, inside an onEdit you should only work on what has just being edited, instead of triggering a full recalculation of your colors because the user edited something on another column or another sheet entirely.

I think your code should be something like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() !== 'Copy of Project Sheet 1' ) return; //only interested in one sheet
  var r = s.getActiveRange();
  var c = r.getColumn();
  if( c !== 4 && c !== 5 ) return; //only interested in changes on columns D or E
  r = r.offset(0, c === 4 ? 0 : -1, 1, 2);
  var v = r.getValues()[0];
  r.setBackgroundColor(v[1] === '' || v[1] > v[0] ? 'red' : v[1] < v[0] ? 'green' : 'white');
}
```

**--edit**

You can not run this function manually directly, because it needs a parameter that is passed only when it runs automatically. But you can emulate it with a test function, like this:

```js
function testEdit() { onEdit({source:SpreadsheetApp.getActive()}); }
```

Comment: when i try to run it i get this error ReferenceError: "eve" is not defined. (line 2, file "c2")

Comment: Well, this must be an error on other code you have. I tested this code and it works. You must have "eve" somewhere else. And by the way, this is not meant to be ran manually, since it needs the event parameter only passed when it runs automatically (see latest edit to answer).